# How do I tell if a text box contains only spaces in c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a textbox which is mandatory field and I have wrote a condition.

But User is entering "    "(only spaces in textbox). In that scenario my code fails. Can anyone please tell me, how to check textbox contains only spaces in textbox.

```
if(txtEmployee.Text == ""|| txtEmployee.Text == null || txtEmployee.Text == " ")
{
     this.lblMessage.CssClass = "messageFail";
     this.lblMessage.Text = "Please Enter Request for";
     return;
}
```

Comment: Why not trim it?

Comment: you can use Regex to replace the space with empty string then check it

Comment: Not exactly the same, but: `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmployee.Text)`

Comment: [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Niladri You *can*. But why make things complicated?

Comment: @Fildor yes i guess that's a point

Comment: @Amit, my bad.  i thought this was mvc.  deleting my comment.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the built-in static method of string IsNullOrWhiteSpace. You can find more info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx.

So your code should look like this:

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmployee.Text))
{
     this.lblMessage.CssClass = "messageFail";
     this.lblMessage.Text = "Please Enter Request for";
     return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of these

```
1. if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmployee.Text.Trim()))

2. if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmployee.Text))

3. if(txtEmployee.Text.Trim()!=string.Empty)

4. if(txtEmployee.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
```

Implementation of IsNullorEmpty and IsNullOrWhitespace from [reference source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/string.cs#L748)

```
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(String value) {
        return (value == null || value.Length == 0);
    }


    public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String value) {
        if (value == null) return true;

        for(int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++) {
            if(!Char.IsWhiteSpace(value[i])) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: null or empty won't work for this case as the OP wants to test for white space

Comment: @Pete Just trimmed it

Comment: `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmployee.Text.Trim()))` I give you a moment to think about this ;-)

Comment: "bzzzzz", out of time; no cookie! The point is; by calling `IsNullOrEmpty` you imply the value can be null, which would lead to a null reference exception because you trim it. If you don't expect `null`, then `1` would be equivalent to `3`. Either way, `2` is the most robust way and should be the only one suggested.

Comment: @Stefan He is using textbox.text, so, obviously if there is a textbox, there would be a text. It will not be null. Check internal implementation of IsNullOrEmpty added in the answer, how short that code is and with a OR condition in the IF. Also, third one is not exactly same as first since there is no null check. Moreso, in asp.net, if you are requiring this check, then you would be needing to trim a value anyways for other use in later lines, may be saving in database. So, if that be the case, the value should first be taken in variable, then trimmed and followed up with.

Comment: Nice folow-up +1 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Check if null or empty & trim

[String.Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.110).aspx)
[String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hi, I think it isn't wise to do a `Trim` on a field on which you are doing a `null` check. `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` would be more appropriate.